# Splitting large strings into words in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have a long string in php consisting of different paragraphs each of which with different sentences (it is pretty much a small document).  I want to split the whole thing into words by removing any symbols/characters that are not relevant.  For example remove commas, spaces, new lines, full stops, exclamation marks and anything that might be irrelevant so as to end up with only words.

Is there an easy way of doing this in one go, for example by using a regular expression and the `preg_split` function or do I have to use the `explode` function a number of times: eg first get all the sentences (by removing '.', '!' etc). Then get words by removing ',' and spaces etc etc.

I would not like to use the `explode` function on all the possible characters that are irrelevant since it is time consuming and I may accidentally omit some of all those possible characters.

I would like to find a more automatic way.  I think a well define regular expression might do the work but again I will need to specify all the possible characters and also I have no idea of how to write regular expressions in php.

So what can you suggest to me ?

Comment: I think you are confusing people by saying you want to "split" the document into words.  That is not what you are trying to do.  You want to remove all the unwanted characters which has quite a different meaning.

Comment: Tell me either white list or black list of characters.

Comment: This question would be much clearer with a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to remove punctuation characters, etc and then split the words into an array? Or just strip it so there are only letters and spaces? Not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, but the following might help:

```
<?php

$string = "This is a sentence! It has *lots* of #$@king random non-word characters. Wouldn't you like to strip them?";

$words = preg_replace("/[^\w\ _]+/", '', $string); // strip all punctuation characters, news lines, etc.
$words = preg_split("/\s+/", $words); // split by left over spaces

var_dump($words);
```

Either way, it gives you the general idea of using regular expressions to manipulate text as needed. My example has two parts, this way words like "wouldn't" aren't split into two words like other answers have suggested.

Comment: Yes I want to remove all the irrelevant characters (punctuation etc) and end of with words represented in an array.

Comment: So taking all the answers together I guest I should first remove all the irrelevant characters ending up with a string of words separated by spaces and then just split spaces to get an array of words.

Comment: My regular expression should remove any irrelevant characters like:
!.£$%^&*()_+-?/~#@':;¬`|\/*
Do I have to include all those individually on it?

Comment: @ Cobby does your solution replace only punctuation and new line characters ? if yes how can I indlude all those characters mentioned above?

Comment: My solution strips all characters that aren't letters, numbers, underscores and spaces. Then it splits the result into words by splitting on any amount of whitespace. I'll update my answer now so that it also strips underscores.

Comment: @user1181539 You should copy my answer code into a script and run it to see the result.

Answer (score 1):

To be unicode compatible, you should use this one:

```
preg_split('/\PL+/u', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

wich splits on characters that are not letter.

Have a look at [here](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) to see the *unicode character properties.*

Answer (score 0):

Just use preg_replace() and define a regular expression to match on the different characters you wish to replace and provide a replacement character to replace them with.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

For the characters you wish to search on you can define those in a PHP array as seen in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in the domain of regular expressions and would probably be very difficult to get right. You could get something that works well in almost all cases but there would be exceptions.

This might help:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html